# Hot water tank won't light

Tags: plumbing

I have a branford white hot water tank that is driving me crazy. I recently flushed it and it's partner (I have two tanks for underfloor heat), and now the pilot will not stay lit. I took the burner out, figuring my thermocouple had died, so I changed that--but problem persists. I press the igniter with the button down, pilot lights.. I've left it like this for over a minute, let go of the button, flame goes out immediately. I also noted, if I turn my tank to "on," turn the thermostat until it calls for heat and hold a lighter to the burner (I know.. Not the safest idea), nothing happens.

I cleaned the pipe for the pilot using a needle... I've tried everything I can think of... Any suggestions?

Comment: When you say tank do you mean to say water heater? You should give the model number  and  if/how the two units work together to assist us in helping you.  Are you sure you got the thermal coupler aligned properly with the pilot light.?

Comment: I'll grab the model number in the morning.. My two tanks are plumbed together in such a, way that they work together to provide underfloor heat and hot water for the house. Im sure the thermocouple is close enough to the flame as I held it directly in the heart of the flame to test it

Comment: any thoughts--it's a branford white mi403s8fbnh7 and I still can't get this thing to work.....it lit twice with a new thermocouple, but then stopped working...